# How to use axios result in various react classes

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have basically an html document with various DOM elements that I want to fill with data coming from react.

```js
<html> .... 

<div id="value1">
....
<div id="value2">

</html>
```

Then I have a index.js file that associates each dom element with a (different) react class:

```js
import ClassName1 from ?...?;
ReactDOM.render(<ClassName1 />, document.getElemnentById('value1'));
```

No I have a React class that does something like that:

```js
class ClassName1 extends Component 

  constructor()
  ...
  componentDidMount() 
    axios-call
     => return value1,value2
```

What I want to achieve is

```js
render(value1 => DOM(1) , value2 => DOM(2))
```

Comment: Do you have any reason to not use a component that makes the call and gives the results to two children ?

Comment: if it is a global data (fetched once) you can use react context

Comment: My HTML document is basically a Dashboard with many different elements that get their data from different sources. (most of them if a firebase database) - So react seems to be the perfect solution for me as I can observe any changes in the DB.. The only exeption is that I also get data from an external website that returns me different values. Of course I want to connect to the website only once and show the values on my website and not for every DOM element seperately..

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do doesn't seem like something you'd want to use react for. But I'll give you two scenarios:

**Scenario 1**: You want two "child components" to render with different values from what you got from the axios call.

The best solution for this is just to render two different components, like so:

```js
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      value1: null,
      value2: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios(someUrl).then(response => {
     const value1 = response.body.value1;
     const value2 = response.body.value2;

     this.setState({ value1, value2 });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <React.Fragment>
        <div id="value1">{value1}</div>
        <div id="value2">{value2}</div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

**Scenario 2**: You want to change other DOM elements that are not part of the react tree.

In this case, you could get the DOM elements by their ID and change the content when the axios call returns, something like this:

```js
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      value1: null,
      value2: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios(someUrl).then(response => {
     const value1 = response.body.value1;
     const value2 = response.body.value2;

     this.setState({ value1, value2 });

     const element1 = document.getElementById('value1');
     element1.innerHTML = value1;

     const element2 = document.getElementById('value2');
     element2.innerHTML = value2;
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(null);
  }
}
```

In scenario 2, you'd be changing stuff outside of react tree... which is unconventional, but it seems to be what you're asking for. Remember that you'll need divs with `value1` and `value2` ids in your DOM before the axios call returns with values.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple answer** (but bad) - You can simply render twice in different root as shown below.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App({ value }) {
  return <div className="App">{value}</div>;
}

const root1 = document.getElementById("root1");
ReactDOM.render(<App value="value1" />, root1);

const root2 = document.getElementById("root2");
ReactDOM.render(<App value="value2" />, root2);
```

[image: Edit soanswer52856523]

But the problem is that, now those two components aren't in the same React tree, thus can't communicate with each other.

If you need a central container that retrieves data but want to pass data, you can use [React Portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) in v16+.

*You can do something crazy like [this](https://hackernoon.com/using-a-react-16-portal-to-do-something-cool-2a2d627b0202) with Portal.*

Suppose that you want to pass `value1` & `value2` to following `div`s.

```js
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <div id="value1">
  <div id="value2">
...
</body>
```

where `root` div is main React tree is mounted on.

You can create a portal by mounting onto those `value1&2` divs like following.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class ValuePortal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.el = document.getElementById(props.elementID);
  }

  render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.value, this.el);
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ValuePortal elementID="value1" value="for value1" />
      <ValuePortal elementID="value2" value="for value2" />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Your main container is mounted in the `root` as shown above and values are displayed using portal component, `ValuePortal`.

You can follow along on CodeSandBox.
[image: Edit soanswer52856523-portal]